# Python compiler call another python compiler to execute a script (execute a script from one independent machine to another)

Tags: python

I know the question title is weird!.

I have two virtual machines. First one has limited resources, while the second one has enough resources just like normal machine. The first machine will receive a signal from an external device. This signal will trigger a python compiler to execute a script. The script is big and the first machine does not have enough resources to execute it.
I can copy the script to the second machine to run it there, but I can't make the second machine receive the external signal. I am wondering if there is a way to make the compiler on the first machine ( once the external signal received) call the compiler on the second machine, so the compiler on the second machine executes the script? so the second compiler should use the second machine resources. check the attached image please.
Assume that the connection is established between the two machines and they can see each other, and the second machine has a copy from the script. I just need the commands that pass ( the execution ) to the second machine and make it use its own resources.
[image]

Comment: Compiler is not the right word here, CPython, at least, is executed on an interpreter in the CPython runtime. In any case, it seems like you are asking how to execute a Python process from another Python process, yes?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think he is asking how to execute a script from one independent machine to another.

Comment: Yes, on another machine, you are right.

Comment: yes exactly. but the second python process should not use the first python process resources. ( each process is in a different machine).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I'm not sure about doing this in Python, but you could probably do this pretty easily with SSH/SCP.

Comment: Just use [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/)

Comment: Thank you donkopotamus for the suggestion. I will try it and respond.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [microservice](https://microservices.io/) architecture to do this.

You can achieve this either by using [`flask`](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) and sending server requests between each machine, or something like [`nameko`](https://github.com/nameko/nameko), which will allow you to create a "bridge" between machines and call functions between them (seems like what you are more interested in). Example for `nameko`:

**Machine 2** (executor of resource-intensive script):

```py
from nameko.rpc import rpc

class Stuff(object):

    @rpc
    def example(self):
        return "Function running on Machine 2."
```

You would run the above script through the Nameko shell, as detailed in the docs.

**Machine 1:**

```py
from nameko.standalone.rpc import ClusterRpcProxy

# This is the amqp server that machine 2 would be running.
config = {
    'AMQP_URI': AMQP_URI  # e.g. "pyamqp://guest:guest@localhost"
}

with ClusterRpcProxy(config) as cluster_rpc:
    cluster_rpc.Stuff.example()  # Function running on Machine 2.
```

More [info](https://nameko.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built_in_extensions.html#rpc) here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I need sometime to check this solution, and I will response soon.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that nameko need a running AMQP server to work.

Comment: @KlausD. Very true. If he checked out the documentation he should find that would be the case. I implied it on the first comment mentioned under "Machine 1", but didn't explicitly say -- you are correct, though, and a good point to keep in mind (at Anmar). https://nameko.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, there's many approaches to this problem.

If you want a python only solution, you can check out

- dispy http://dispy.sourceforge.net/
- Or Dask. https://dask.org/

If you want a robust solution (what I use on my home computing cluster but imo overkill for your problem) you can use

- SLURM. SLURM is basically a way to string multiple computers together into a "supercomputer". https://slurm.schedmd.com/documentation.html

For a semi-quick, hacky solution. You can write a microservice. Essentially, your "weak" computer will receive the message then send a http request to your "strong" computer. Your strong computer will contain the actual program, compute results, and pass back the result to your "weak" computer.

- Flask is an easy and lightweight solution for this.

All of these solutions require some type of networking. At the least, the computers need to be on the same LAN or both have access over the web.

There are many other approaches not mentioned. For example, you can export a NFS (netowrk file storage) and have one computer put a file in the shared folder and the other computer perform work on the file. I'm sure there are plenty other contrived ways to accomplish this task :). I'd be happy to expand on a particular method if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I need sometime to check this solution, and I will response soon.